# Is this technique acceptable for constructing ParseResults in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I feel that `ParseActions` make my code a bit clunky when trying to construct the resulting parse tree (known as `ParseResults` in pyparsing).

What I'm doing now is to have global variables that store groups of matched tokens that are returned by the `Group` element. Then at the end, I will inject the results back into the `toks` dictionary. Is this ok ?

My sketchy grammar:

```
grammar = ZeroOrMore( Or( ExprA, ExprB, ExprC ) )
```

Note that `ExprA`, `ExprB` etc. can interleave in any order. But I want to group all expressions of one type into one dictionary entry in ParseResults. What do you think of my technique ? I don't like to use global variables because it makes multithreading a problem. Do I have other choices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about using setResultsName with listAllMatches=True?  Here's a demo:

```
from pyparsing import *

aExpr = Word("A", nums)
bExpr = Word("B", nums)
cExpr = Word("C", nums)

grammar = ZeroOrMore(aExpr.setResultsName("A",listAllMatches=True) |
                     bExpr.setResultsName("B",listAllMatches=True) |
                     cExpr.setResultsName("C",listAllMatches=True) )


results = grammar.parseString("A1 B1 A2 C1 B2 A3")
print results.dump()
```

prints:

```
['A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'C1', 'B2', 'A3']
- A: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
- B: ['B1', 'B2']
- C: ['C1']
```

EDIT:

The newer form for this would be:

```
grammar = ZeroOrMore(aExpr("A*") | bExpr("B*") | cExpr("C*") )
```

I found `".setResultsName"` to be too verbose and cluttering when defining grammars, which worked against my intention of encouraging people to use results names.